# how to display @2x image from database

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios6

I've integrated Facebook framework for ios 6.I'm fetching my friends details from the facebook and inserting into the sqlite database.and then this information is displaying in my application.while displaying image,the image quality is not good.image looks stretched.so,how can i fetch image with @2x extension

Comment: is the image in the db? provide some more information?

Comment: i ' m just inserting image name in the db..images are saved in library folder.

Answer (score 1):

Only thing you have to do is to adopt the @2x naming convention

Standard: .
Example: circle.png

High resolution: @2x.
Example: circle@2x.png